# MS-Access Resize Textbox or Label in Group section of Report

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to resize either a textbox, label or box on an MS-Access Report to show percent complete as a bar.

I am getting an error that says the setting you entered isn't valid for this property.

In the example below, the blue progress bar should be the completion % for each department.  If the grey bar is 100%, the blue progress bar should be 95.3% of the grey bar for transportation, 99.0% for mechanical and 95.1% for engineering.

```
Private Sub GroupHeader4_Paint()

 Box188.Width = <completeion %>

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Box188 width as percent of TotalMonth control width.
me.Box188.width = me.TotalMonth.width * completion

You should provide variable 'completion' from reports recordset.